# How to create generic abstract method that accepts different enums?

Tags: java, generics, enums

How can I create abstract generic method doSomething() that accepts different enums? Enum1 and Enum2, Enum3 and so on?

```java
public abstract class NumerOne {
    
    public abstract void doSomething();
    
    }
```

```
public class NumberTwo extends NumberOne {
    @Override
    public void doSomething (Enum1 enum1) {
        enum1.createSomething();
    }
```

Comment: I tried public abstract <T> void doSomething(T object); but it does not work

Comment: Did you define a bound for `T`? Like `<T extends Enum<T>>`? And explain not working - what are desired and actual results.

Comment: You cannot override `doSomething` that way, as the signature in `NumberTwo` does not match the one in `NumberOne`.

Answer (score 2):

The most appropriate way to accept a handful of Enum types, but not accept any enum (`<T extends Enum<T>`) or (even worse) `Object` would be to create an interface and have all the enums that you want to accept implement that interface:

```
interface CreatorOfSomething {
    // I have no idea what type should be returned here,
    // as you don't use this value in your example.
    // But I'm pretty sure it can't be void, so I'll go with Integer.
    // You can have this parameterised as <T> at the interface level.
    Integer createSomething();
}

enum Enum1 implements CreatorOfSomething {
    A, B, C;
    @Override
    public Integer createSomething() {
        return ordinal();
    }
}

enum Enum2 implements CreatorOfSomething {
    X { // you can override the method for individual constants
        @Override
        public Integer createSomething() {
            // .....
        }
    },
    Y { ....
}
```

Then your method would look like:

```
public void doSomething(CreatorOfSomething creator) {
    creator.createSomething();
}
```

Comment: A couple of side notes:
(1) `doSomething` now accepts anything that implements `CreatorOfSomething`, including a lambda function, and you should consider annotating it as `@FunctionalInterface` (if it's supposed to have a single method);

(2) you don't necessarily need an dedicated interface for this "creator", as you can make the enums implement the `java.util.function.Supplier` interface.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not even compile. Nor could we run it. Next time please provide an [SSCCE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) in which you address your question.

Here's the solution for the problem you have:

```
abstract class NumberOne {
    public abstract <T extends Enum<T>> void doSomething(T pEnum);
}

enum Enum1 {
    A, B
}
enum Enum2 {
    C, D
}

public class NumberTwo extends NumberOne {

    @Override public <T extends Enum<T>> void doSomething(final T pEnum) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + pEnum);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final NumberTwo n2 = new NumberTwo();
        n2.doSomething(Enum1.A);
        n2.doSomething(Enum2.D);
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not work:  @Override public <T extends Enum<T>> void doSomething(final T pEnum) {
        //here I want to invoke a specific method that I have in Enum, so pEnum.mySpecificMethod() throws error "cannot resolve method..."
    }

Comment: Then go with @CostiCiudatu 's code. I didn't realize you wanted to interface the enums. He's got the proper solution in nice detail.